# Telerik Grid Toolbar insert - show custom text

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, telerik

I would like to customize the TEXT of the generic insert button. Currently it is "Create new record".

Here is my code.

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{

    toolbar.Insert().ImageHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "t-icon t-add", title = "Create new inventory" });
})
```

Comment: @JABFreeware I would assume that "Create new inventory" is not appearing in the insert button text.

Comment: Could you post a small pic of the button you're trying to customize?  Also, wouldn't the button be an image URL button, so you would have to customize the image itself?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Text()` method to set the text of the button.

```
toolbar.Insert().Text("Create new inventory")
```

And make sure you are using an up-to-date version. That method was added in a recent release.